# I want to send a verification link to users email without using firebase authentication [Flutter]

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cross-platform

A website is already made up and I have to make application of that website using flutter but the website is not using Firebase authentication and sending email verification link to the registering user . I want to do the same same thing using flutter that is send a verification link to the users mail and get status if the user is verified or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this SMTP(Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) we are using,

**in flutter**
there is package [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer)

it is an easy to use library for composing and sending emails in Dart.

Mailer supports file attachments and HTML emails.

Comment: How to generate verification link and implement the verification functunality